# Trying to scrape Moodys local table from this web and getting character(empty) as value

Tags: r, web-scraping, web

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.moodyslocal.com/country/pe/ratings/insurance"

page <- read_html(url)

headers <- page%>%html_nodes('.tabledata-cell')%>%html_text()
```

I have tried with html_table, different class, etc. Also when I run for instance this: page%>%html_nodes('h1'), I get this output {xml_nodeset (0)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data for the table is in another location, which you can find by checking which resourcse are loaded over the network after you visit the page in a normal browser.

Try this:

```r
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

## url <- "https://www.moodyslocal.com/country/pe/ratings/insurance"
url <- "https://www.moodyslocal.com/api/countries/PE/ratings?sector=Insurance"

table_src <- read_json(url)

table_data <- table_src %>%
    map(  ~ as_tibble(.x[["es"]]) ) %>%
    list_rbind()
```

Output:

```
> head(table_data)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  entity                                                   sector    analyst outlook date  curre…¹ previ…² instruments 
  <chr>                                                    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <list>      
1 Avla Perú Compañía de Seguros S.A.                       Insurance Solans… -       2022… /count… /count… <named list>
2 BNP Paribas Cardif S.A. Compañía de Seguros y Reaseguros Insurance Laura … Estable 2023… /count… /count… <named list>
3 Chubb Seguros Perú S.A.                                  Insurance Laura … Estable 2023… /count… /count… <named list>
4 Crecer Seguros S.A. Compañía de Seguros                  Insurance Jennif… Estable 2023… /count… /count… <named list>
5 InSur S.A. Compañía de Seguros                           Insurance Jennif… Estable 2023… /count… /count… <named list>
6 Interseguro Compañía de Seguros S.A.                     Insurance Roco P… Estable 2023… /count… /count… <named list>
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​currentReport, ²​previousReport
>
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! It worked however I had to run these lines

config <- httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0)

response = GET(Pag1)
content <- content(response, as = "text")

After this it worked.

Comment: that's weird. I do not have to do those steps. I did have to add library(jsonlite) though, for the read_json function, but you maybe already had that.